# Concatenate array elements in MongoDB 3.4 with Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**What I have :**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577dc9d61a0b7e0a40499f90"), "equ" : 123456, "key" : "p" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577c789b1a0b7e0a403f1b52"), "equ" : 123456, "key" : "r" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577b27481a0b7e0a4033965a"), "equ" : 123456, "key" : "r" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5779d6111a0b7e0a40282dc7"), "equ" : 123456, "key" : "o" }
```

**What I want :**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5779d6111a0b7e0a40282dc7"), "equ" : 123456, "keys" : "prro" }
```

**What I tried :**

`db.table.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":0, "keys":{"$push":"$key"}}}])` 
returns an array and not a string:

```
{"_id":0, "keys":["p","r","r","o"]}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why did you choose `ObjectId("5779d6111a0b7e0a40282dc7")`? Since it's the last one?

Comment: Do not take ObjectId into account. I don't care about the id, only equ and keys matters.

Comment: Then there is no need to maintain the last id and then projecting it, as I did in my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## TL; DR

---

Use this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$equ", last: {$last: "$_id"}, keys: {$push: "$key"}}},
    {
        $project: {
            equ: "$_id",
            _id: "$last",
            keys: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$keys",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {$concat: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

## More details

---

First you should [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) the documents based on the `equ` value and also maintain an [array of keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) along with the `_id` of the [last group member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last):

```
var groupByEqu = {
    $group: {
        _id: "$equ",
        last: {$last: "$_id"},
        keys: {$push: "$key"}
    }
}
```

Just applying this pipeline operation would result in:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 123456, 
    "last" : ObjectId("5779d6111a0b7e0a40282dc7"), 
    "keys" : [ "p", "r", "r", "o" ] 
}
```

You should use a *Projection* to transform the preceding document into your desired one. The first two transformations are trivial. For joining the array elements you can use the new [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator:

```
var project = {
    $project: {
        equ: "$_id",
        _id: "$last",
        keys: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$keys",
                initialValue: "",
                in: {$concat: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Applying these two pipeline operations would give you the desired result:

```
db.col.aggregate([groupByEqu, project])
```

Which is:

```
{ 
    "equ" : 123456, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5779d6111a0b7e0a40282dc7"), 
    "keys" : "prro"
}
```